# Images and product info not showing up on page

Tags: php, html, css, mysqli

Been working on a product page for my wife's jewelry site. I added php from a tutorial and tried to run the page. None of the images including the header showed up along with the footer. They show up on every other page. None of the information product showed up either. the page says connection opened and i receive no errors. The navigation shows up along with some of the css but that is all.

Here is my code I am using.

```
       <?php 
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        ?>
        <?php 
        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
            // Connect to the MySQL database  
            include_once("storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php");
            $con = 





              mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass","$db_name"); 

            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_errno());
            exit();


        } $id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['id']); 
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category='Bracelets';";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                // get all the product details
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)); { 
                     $item_number = $row["item_number"];
                     $price = $row["price"];
                     $desc = $row["description"];
                     $category = $row["category"];
                 }

            } else {
                echo "Data to render this page is missing.";
                exit();
            }
        }
        ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>Bracelets</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="x=UA-comparable" content="IE-edge">
            <meta name="description" content="Pinky's Pearls is a website where 
            one 
            of a kind jewelry designed by Nichole <q>Nicki</q> can be seen and 
            purchased">
            <meta name="keywords" content="jewelry, beads, bracelets, rings, 
            pendants, necklaces, pearls, crystal">
            <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <meta name="author" content="samuel jaycox">
            <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="stylesheet" 
             href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font- 
            awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
            <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="pictures/pinky.png">
            <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/0c9491c5b9.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div align="center"  id="wrapper">
            <div id="banner-wrapper">
            <?php 



  include_once("c:/xampp/htdocs/pinkys_pearls/templates/template_bracelets.php"); 
            ?>
                <br>
            <?php include_once("templates/template_navigation.php"); ?>     
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
        <!--Start Comment page Body Content-->
        <div id="body-content">
            <div class="bracelet_body">
                <table width="100%" border="2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="15">
          <tr>
            <td width="19%" valign="top"><img src="pictures/inventory/<?php echo 
        $pid; ?>.png" width="142" height="188" alt="<?php echo $item_number; ?>" 
        /> 
       <br />
              <a href="pictures/inventory/<?php echo $pid; ?>.png">View Full Size 
        Image</a></td>
            <td width="81%" valign="top"><h3><?php echo $item_number; ?></h3>
              <p><?php echo "$".$price; ?><br />
                <br />
                <?php echo $desc; ?>
        <br />
                </p>
              <form  id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="cart.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="<?php echo $id; ? 
         >" 
        />
                <input class="button" type="submit" name="button" id="button" 
       value="Add to Shopping Cart" />
              </form>
              </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--end of Comment body-->
        <?php include_once('templates/template_footer.php'); ?>">
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Where did you define `$pid` in your html section?

Comment: Check with your url inside `include_once`. Is it in same directory? if yes don't use url like `c:/xampp/htdocs` and where is your footer i am not able to see any footer you are including in your HTML

Comment: I accidentally took out the footer section while working on it last night. I redid the php and the footer and navigation showed up but the header still did not. It shows up in the viewer in dreamweaver. Still can't get the product info either.

Comment: $pid was defined on the inventory_list page when items are put into the database. It is the variable for the picture id.

Answer (score 0):

**Please make sure your paths are right!**

Try to change your links

`<?php include_once("c:/xampp/htdocs/pinkys_pearls/templates/template_bracelets.php"); ?>`

`<?php include_once("c:/xampp/htdocs/pinkys_pearls/templates/template_navigation.php"); ?>`

as

`<?php include_once("localhost/pinkys_pearls/templates/template_bracelets.php"); ?>`

`<?php include_once("localhost/pinkys_pearls/templates/template_navigation.php"); ?>`

and **make sure with your image paths**, if folder varies you cannot get load the images.

Comment: I have double checked the paths and redid the php. I still do not get the information from the database. Another words I need all information from the row category with the value of bracelets. My new php is at top,

Comment: Hey hi, please use inspect element in crome browser then go-to console tab menu see the errors showing. This will help you

Comment: This is what the console said: [Deprecation] Resource requests whose URLs contained both removed whitespace (\n, \r, \t) characters and less-than characters (<) are blocked. Please remove newlines and encode less-than characters from places like element attribute values in order to load these resources. See chromestatus.com/feature/5735596811091968 for more details. – Samuel Jaycox 15 hours ago